# React-Native Firebase Firestore query , find document by timestamp field problem

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, field

I'm trying to get just one document from firestore, which has a field **date** .
Here is my function, which I call on press a date from Calendar. I convert it to unix timestamp. The problem is that snapshot is empty. I expect to get just one object.

Can you help me, to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot.
Here is my function.

```
getDailyData = (day) => {
    const unix = dayjs(day).unix();
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(this.state.currentUser.uid)
      .collection("dailyData")
      .where("date", "==", unix)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });   };
```

[Picture from my firestore DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEiXS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the date object instead of the unix timestamp, which I assume is a number.
If this does not work, try to use a [firestore timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) when querying.